# Support for audio and webcam on Dell XPS 13 9315 2-in-1?

Tags: drivers, sound, dell, webcam

Ubuntu 22.04.1LTS is mostly running on my XPS 13 9315 2-in-1.  However,
Sound shows only a Dummy Device, and Webcam has "Device: Virtual Camera" which is color bars.  This model is not certified for Ubuntu, but similar ones are.  [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428961/dell-xps-13-webcam-not-recognized-under-ubuntu-22-04-1) describes setting up OEM PPAs for Dell machines.  Does anyone know which are the best possible matches for my XPS 13 9315 2-in-1?

Windows Device Manager shows a "Realtek SoundWire HW Audio Codec Device Driver" (rtksdwhwcodec_dell). [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258583/install-realtek-audio-drivers-in-ubuntu-20-04-intel-nuc-nuc10i7fnh/1328544#1328544) suggests that a solution might be to give a "model=" option to snd-hda-intel, but the suggested one "dell-headset-multi" didn't work for this model.  There are a couple of possible Realtek sound related kernel modules loaded (snd_soc_rt715_sdca and snd_soc_rt1316_sdw) but I don't know how to get the speakers and microphone array activated.

Comment: I have this issue as well, on my 9315. Or... I have no audio device or webcam. In addition, I'm getting glitches in video. It seems to be doing brightness sensing and auto-britness, maybe that's why. It feels pretty unstable on this "laptop". :-\

Comment: I didn't care for the auto-brightness either, but I was able to turn it off under Settings->Power.

Comment: I have six xps13 9315 2 in 1's and the speakers/microphone and video, don't work, with Ubuntu 22.04.2, Kernel = 5.19.0-38-generic. 
And I have two xps13 9315's, here the speakers and microphone work but the video still doesn't. 

Usually its switching to the correct OEM kernel from Ubuntu, that Dell sets up.

On one 2 in 1, I tried the OEM PPAs, but it didn't address the issues. 

So I'm looking for someone who has been successful for this.