# Dummy Output Dell XPS 13 9315 Audio not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dell, alsa

No audio output. There are several posts I've been referencing to try to get drivers and settings configured correctly, but I've had no success.
There are several [unanswered questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450392/support-for-audio-and-webcam-on-dell-xps-13-9315-2-in-1) on here about the issue. Someone on [Reddit appears to have gotten it working](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/16y9jsz/on_the_dell_xps_2in1_9315_and_audio/?rdt=63648) with 22.04, but I was unable to replicate their configuration.

Configuration:
[Alsa information script](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=f08800e95af5b72316443b8d7c7db2bb1bc25428)

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.5.3
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Sun Nov 26 16:33:38 UTC 2023


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS" PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Dell Inc.
Product Name:      XPS 13 9315 2-in-1
Product Version:   
Firmware Version:  1.5.0
System SKU:        0B34
Board Vendor:      Dell Inc.
Board Name:        03Y9WX


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000E:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DLLK0B34:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A1:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D3:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D4:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT346D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3472:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3472:07/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3537:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1041:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1046:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1046:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1046:02/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1046:03/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1046:04/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1055:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1070:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1099:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:00/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:04/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT8000:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/OVTI00AB:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:02/status      8
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:04/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:05/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP00001:00/status     11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP00001:01/status     11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/STM0125:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/USBC000:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/WACF3233:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:01/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:0f/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:10/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:7d/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:85/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:86/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:87/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:89/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:8a/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:8b/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:bf/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:c6/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:c8/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:ca/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    #38~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov  2 18:01:13 UTC 2
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k6.2.0-37-generic
Library version:    1.2.6.1
Utilities version:  1.2.6


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp (card 0)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

PipeWire:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pipewire)
      Running - Yes

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      DellInc.-XPS1393152_in_1--03Y9WX


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

0000:00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51cc] (rev 01) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0b34]


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
    * : 


!!Sysfs card info
!!---------------

!!Card: /sys/class/sound/card0
Driver: /sys/bus/platform/drivers/skl_hda_dsp_generic
Tree:
    /sys/class/sound/card0
    |-- controlC0
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- device -> ../../../skl_hda_dsp_generic
    |-- hwC0D2
    |   |-- afg
    |   |-- chip_name
    |   |-- clear
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- driver_pin_configs
    |   |-- hints
    |   |-- init_pin_configs
    |   |-- init_verbs
    |   |-- mfg
    |   |-- modelname
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- power_off_acct
    |   |-- power_on_acct
    |   |-- reconfig
    |   |-- revision_id
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   |-- subsystem_id
    |   |-- uevent
    |   |-- user_pin_configs
    |   |-- vendor_id
    |   `-- vendor_name
    |-- id
    |-- input22
    |   |-- capabilities
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- event12
    |   |-- id
    |   |-- inhibited
    |   |-- modalias
    |   |-- name
    |   |-- phys
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- properties
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/input
    |   |-- uevent
    |   `-- uniq
    |-- input23
    |   |-- capabilities
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- event13
    |   |-- id
    |   |-- inhibited
    |   |-- modalias
    |   |-- name
    |   |-- phys
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- properties
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/input
    |   |-- uevent
    |   `-- uniq
    |-- input24
    |   |-- capabilities
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- event14
    |   |-- id
    |   |-- inhibited
    |   |-- modalias
    |   |-- name
    |   |-- phys
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- properties
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/input
    |   |-- uevent
    |   `-- uniq
    |-- number
    |-- pcmC0D1p
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- pcmC0D2p
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- pcmC0D3p
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- power
    |   |-- async
    |   |-- autosuspend_delay_ms
    |   |-- control
    |   |-- runtime_active_kids
    |   |-- runtime_active_time
    |   |-- runtime_enabled
    |   |-- runtime_status
    |   |-- runtime_suspended_time
    |   `-- runtime_usage
    |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../class/sound
    `-- uevent


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: Intel Alderlake-P HDMI
Address: 2
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x8086281c
Subsystem Id: 0x80860101
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0, Clock-stop-OK
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
Node 0x05 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
Node 0x07 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x08 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
Node 0x09 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1a]: 16 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x0a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
Node 0x0b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
Node 0x0c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
Node 0x0d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
Node 0x0e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
Node 0x0f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Devices: 0
  Connection: 0
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  6 Nov 26 11:22 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  5 Nov 26 11:22 /dev/snd/hwC0D2
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  2 Nov 26 11:22 /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  3 Nov 26 11:22 /dev/snd/pcmC0D2p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  4 Nov 26 11:22 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  1 Nov 26 11:22 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 33 Nov 26 11:22 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Nov 26 11:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 200 Nov 26 11:22 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Nov 26 11:22 pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic -> ../controlC0


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 2: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card sofhdadsp

Card sysdefault:0 'sofhdadsp'/'DellInc.-XPS1393152_in_1--03Y9WX'
  Mixer name    : 'Intel Alderlake-P HDMI'
  Components    : 'HDA:8086281c,80860101,00100000'
  Controls      : 24
  Simple ctrls  : 6
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'PGA2.0 2 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA3.0 3 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA4.0 4 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
state.sofhdadsp {
    control.1 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=1 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.2 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.3 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.4 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.5 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.6 {
        iface PCM
        device 1
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.7 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=2 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.8 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        index 1
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.9 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        index 1
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.10 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        index 1
        value '0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.11 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        index 1
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.12 {
        iface PCM
        device 2
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.13 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.14 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        index 2
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.15 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        index 2
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.16 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        index 2
        value '0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.17 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        index 2
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.18 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.19 {
        iface PCM
        device 1
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.20 {
        iface PCM
        device 2
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.21 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.22 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'PGA2.0 2 Master Playback Volume'
        value.0 32
        value.1 32
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 32'
            dbmin -9999999
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
    control.23 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'PGA3.0 3 Master Playback Volume'
        value.0 32
        value.1 32
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 32'
            dbmin -9999999
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
    control.24 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'PGA4.0 4 Master Playback Volume'
        value.0 32
        value.1 32
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 32'
            dbmin -9999999
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
}
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

ac97_bus
acpi_pad
acpi_tad
acpi_thermal_rel
aesni_intel
af_alg
ahci
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
autofs4
binfmt_misc
bluetooth
bnep
btbcm
btintel
btmtk
btrtl
btusb
ccm
cec
cfg80211
clk_tps68470
cmac
cmdlinepart
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
dcdbas
dell_laptop
dell_smbios
dell_wmi
dell_wmi_ddv
dell_wmi_descriptor
dell_wmi_sysman
drm
drm_buddy
drm_display_helper
drm_kms_helper
ecc
ecdh_generic
efi_pstore
firmware_attributes_class
ghash_clmulni_intel
hi556
hid
hid_generic
hid_multitouch
hid_sensor_accel_3d
hid_sensor_als
hid_sensor_custom
hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge
hid_sensor_gyro_3d
hid_sensor_hub
hid_sensor_iio_common
hid_sensor_magn_3d
hid_sensor_rotation
hid_sensor_trigger
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_hid_acpi
i2c_i801
i2c_smbus
i915
idma64
igen6_edac
industrialio
industrialio_triggered_buffer
input_leds
int3400_thermal
int3403_thermal
int340x_thermal_zone
intel_cstate
intel_hid
intel_ish_ipc
intel_ishtp
intel_ishtp_hid
intel_lpss
intel_lpss_pci
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_skl_int3472_discrete
intel_skl_int3472_tps68470
ip_tables
irqbypass
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
joydev
kfifo_buf
kvm
kvm_intel
ledtrig_audio
libahci
libarc4
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
mc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
mei_pxp
msr
mtd
nls_iso8859_1
nvme
nvme_common
nvme_core
parport
parport_pc
pinctrl_tigerlake
polyval_clmulni
polyval_generic
ppdev
processor_thermal_device
processor_thermal_device_pci
processor_thermal_mbox
processor_thermal_rapl
processor_thermal_rfim
rapl
rc_core
regmap_sdw
regmap_sdw_mbq
rfcomm
sch_fq_codel
serio_raw
sha512_ssse3
snd
snd_compress
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_ext_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_intel_sdw_acpi
snd_pcm
snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_soc_acpi
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_dmic
snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi
snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common
snd_soc_rt1316_sdw
snd_soc_rt715_sdca
snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_sof
snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_probes
snd_sof_utils
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp
snd_timer
soc_button_array
soundcore
soundwire_bus
soundwire_cadence
soundwire_generic_allocation
soundwire_intel
sparse_keymap
spi_intel
spi_intel_pci
spi_nor
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
thunderbolt
tls
tps68470_regulator
ttm
typec
typec_ucsi
ucsi_acpi
uhid
usbhid
v4l2_async
v4l2_fwnode
v4l2loopback
video
videodev
vmd
wacom
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas


!!Sysfs Files
!!-----------

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/init_pin_configs:
0x04 0x18560010
0x06 0x18560010
0x08 0x18560010
0x0a 0x18560010
0x0b 0x18560010
0x0c 0x18560010
0x0d 0x18560010
0x0e 0x18560010
0x0f 0x18560010

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/hints:


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------



!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.5.1-2                                 all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.8                        all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.6-1ubuntu1                            amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

Linux n00b here, been using linux for many years but I'm a basic user.
My next steps I believe is to try and install/configure pipewire. But I'm really not sure if it's a driver issue, or a configuration problem with pulseaudio and alsamixer.

Update 12/19/2023: Installing pipewire did not fix the issue. I've also consistently gotten a "System program problem detected" on boot, with no additional details. Unsure if issue is related.

Edit- Alsa Mixer screenshot:
[image]

Comment: The reddit post mentions sof. On Ubuntu, I think the package should be `firmware-sof-signed` so have you tried installing this package? `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install firmware-sof-signed` You can search available packages with something like `apt-cache search sof` and you can filter results using grep `apt-cache search sof | grep sof` or even better `apt-cache search sof | grep SOF`

Comment: Also, it usually helps to try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/800280/) when you get a dummy output. The actions will replace any missing or messed up configuration files with the default configuration files in case you used to have it working and now it's not. There are other answers on the page that may or may not apply as well.

Comment: Thanks mchid, I did already try the firmware-sof-signed with no change, and I've done several re-installs of packages with no success including retrying a fresh install of Ubuntu. I'll edit in the alsamixer display and see if that provides any insights.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: I have the same problem. No audio output until I uninstall and reinstall pulse audio and then alsa force reload.

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload

But that only works until the next restart. Very annoying.

Comment: Interestingly, the sound works under Linux Mint 21.3. Edge is required for the WiFi but the sound works on the 5.x kernel in the default installation. This is the second laptop I've had where sound works in Mint but not other Ubunutu-based distros. I've never understood why.